# Jupyter Notebook authentication token while in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

I am trying to use the Jupyter notebook in Pycharm, but I realized that in the new Jupyter update, there was the addition of tokens.

I am following the tutorial below from [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/tutorial-using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html).

With all the settings initiated with the virtual environment created and setting the URL as `127.0.0.1:8888`, however, when I click on the run cell button, it follows that I get the following message from Jupyter Notebook asking:

> Please, enter your Jupyter Notebook URL and authentication token

like this:

[image: PyCharm error message: Enter Jupyter Notebook URL authentication token]

I looked it up on the Jupyter update blog and it says that my web browser should be initiated which generates a token for access, but I do not see that my browser is loaded here.

Help would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: Since at least PyCharm version 2019.1 (and perhaps the latest versions released in 2018), **support for Jupyter notebooks has been removed from the Community edition of PyCharm**. Jupyter notebooks are now only supported in the Professional edition.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Running `jupyter notebook list` will display all of the running servers on your machine. So doing this in the terminal after starting a cell in PyCharm will result in output similar to 

`Currently running servers:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=f85145dda03dc598bbbfa6e53b93cbcb27629ea00cfd2105 :: /home/....`

which contains the appropriate token for authenticating.

Comment: Token in this example is `f85145dda03dc598bbbfa6e53b93cbcb27629ea00cfd2105` (i.e. the string that follows `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=`)

Comment: Running a cell didn't start a jupyter notebook server for me. `jupyter notebook list` returned nothing. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45716341/119775) did work for me, so it's worth trying as well if this one doesn't work for you, the reader.

Comment: If it doesn't work, PyCharm gets stuck in a loop and must be kill -9'd. Cancel doesn't work.

Comment: I only get this : jupyter notebook list: Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/ :: C:\Users\Hemmat

Comment: This answer did not work for me, hence I used [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54693525/3484477) which works perfectly.

Answer (score 54):

1. Edit/enter the URL as: **`http://localhost:8888`** (remove `"?token="` at the end) and click **OK**.
2. A bubble prompt will appear near the top of your PyCharm window, saying "Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook. Run Jupyter Notebook". It should look like this (depending on your color scheme):

[image: PyCharm prompt: Cannot connect to Jypyter Notebook. Run Jupyter Notebook]

4. **Click on the link: "Run Jupyter Notebook"**
5. PyCharm will start the Jupyter server for you and it will create a **new token**. Look at View -> Tool Windows ->  Run, to see details of the new token, and an optional URL to open in a web browser.

More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html

Comment: not working in the latest update of pycharm as for today

Comment: I clicked on the "Run Jupyter Notebook" link and see this returned: [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
[W 08:17:43.929 NotebookApp] Permission to listen on port 8888 denied
[C 08:17:43.929 NotebookApp] ERROR: the notebook server could not be started because no available port could be found.

Comment: @JasonArg123 Does it work if you try the following instructions, to add the extra path to your Run Configuration? ... https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001212999/comments/360000277280

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti: See the answer by "debugging XD", especially the PyCharm Terminal way.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way I found:
If you type `jupyter notebook` in a PowerShell terminal, PowerShell will automatically print out the localhost, port, and token that `PyCharm` needs to run.

You can run the command from PyCharm Terminal so it will go to the same interpreter if you have several.

Comment: Running the command from PyCharm Terminal is the shorter of the two shortest ways. ;)

Answer (score 3):

For the people like me, who don't know where is the *terminal* ->Another way which I find easier is:

1) open new Jupyter notebook in your browser. Look at the URL, there you can see your localhost (example: localhost:8889) and change the default one at PyCharm if necessary.

2) for the token, while you are in the browser press F12 and then Ctrl + F and search for 'token'. It would be somewhere there in the html code, a long string of random numbers and letters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Anaconda Navigator
2. Create Or Open New Notebook
3. Press F12 Or Inspect Element
4. Search For 'token' in its html code
5. You Can Find something like
   this : 'data-jupyter-api-token="02eaf15f7fb715725c85602867d0b2585962e0ee...."'

Answer (score 1):

**I had to reinstall Anaconda and some old config files for my Jupyter Notebook. Check for possible existing jupyter config file, that could contain a password or Token in some cases:**

- open terminal
- Check for jupyter configuration directory:

  jupyter --config-dir

  (example output)>>> C:\Users\Username.jupyter

**open the file and check if "NotebookApp" is assigned in the file:**

```
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "password": "sha1:1af4568a9g:64gsded68g4dsh434df634fhd684"
  }
}
```