# Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm Pro enter authentication token

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook within pycharm pro.  I am running within a virtual environment. This is selected as my project interpreter.

Upon trying to run a cell of the jupyter notebook I get the message - "Please enter the authentication token". I have entered my token as specified in this question - [Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736309/jupyter-notebook-in-pycharm)

Pycharm then says - 'Connecting to Jupyter Notebook Server' (see below). This bar just hangs and nothing happens.

[image]

My notebook was working fine until I tried to create a second notebook. I deleted the second notebook and now the first notebook won't work either.

I am running on OS Sierra 10.12.5, Pycharm Pro 2017.1.4, Python 3.5.1, Jupyter 1.0.0

Comment: I think this happened because I had multiple notebooks running. Make sure you close all running notebooks. And then try and again

Answer (score -1):

Just don't click the link when the notebook starts. It works for me.

Comment: what link? You have to enter the auth token