# Why can't I create jupyter notebook and open ipynb correctly in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Just as follow picture.

'Jupyter Notebook' doesn't in new menu.

File '*.ipynb' is opened as text.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Matthew Barlowe I have opened ipynb successful in pycharm, but I updated my pycharm, then I  encounter this problem. You can see this question, It proves that pycharm can open ipynb, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736309/jupyter-notebook-in-pycharm.

Comment: Then i stand corrected you still need to start the jupyter notebook server first it seems I'd make sure you have that running.

Comment: @Matthew Barlowe Yes, I have started the jupyter notebook server, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Matthew Barlowe Anyway, thanks for your reply. ^_^

Comment: @张庆昊 Have you sloved your problem?

Comment: @kruxx  Yes, you should download the Professional version instead of the Community version. I think Jet Brains removed this function from Community version in a version update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the Professional version instead of the Community version. 
I think Jet Brains removed this function from Community version in a version update.